# Sending EOT via R Socket

Tags: json, r, sockets

i'm currently trying to process data in R coming from a TCP Server Socket using JSON syntax.

My Script is actually able to Connect to the Server via

```
socketConnection(host = "whateverhost", port = "8080", server = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

i parse my JSON objects via

```
writeChar(con = server, object = "{ \"whar\" : \"whatwhar\" }", eos = NULL);
```

After my JSON String i need to pass an EOT-Character (documentation mentions ASCII 4) to the Server to complete my query.

It tried it by

```
writeChar(con = server, object = as.character(04), eos = NULL);
```

But could not get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?!

Thank you !

Comment: does `object = rawToChar(as.raw(4))` work?

Comment: tried that, but sadly it did not help

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer but I need to show an image to the OP**

I fired up a `netcat` server to listen on 8080:

```
nc -l 8080
```

I then setup `tcpdump` to capture packets:

```
tcpdump -i lo0 dst port 8080 -w 8080.dmp
```

I then ran your connection code and initial JSON send code.

Then, whether I use the straight unicode representation:

```
writeChar(con = server, object = "\U0004", eos = NULL)
```

or, the more indirect conversion way to generate the same thing:

```
writeChar(con = server, object = rawToChar(as.raw(4)), eos = NULL)
```

I see EOT (the `04` highlighted in the hex dump portion from the wireshark data segment view).

Are you 100% sure it's a standard EOT the system is expecting? Is the remote system expecting anything after it? Are there other network components buffering anything?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your enthusiasm... Ich gave it a few more tries and adding the '\u0004' to the String itsself solved my problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: Just pointing out that R is doing what it claims to be doing and is sending what your server says it needs. There's something else going on since R is doing it's job. Plus it ended up being a decent example to help others potentially see how to troubleshoot a problem.